# Change propety Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top in codebehind WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, winrt-xaml

```
<Button x:Name="PlayButton" Content="Play" Canvas.Left="570" Canvas.Top="36" Height="51" Width="202" Background="#FF8898F9" />
```

How change Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left property of PlayButton in the code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Canvas` class has [`SetTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SetLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft(v=vs.110).aspx) static methods that set these attached properties:

```
Canvas.SetTop(PlayButton, 36);
Canvas.SetLeft(PlayButton, 750);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Canvas.SetLeft(PlayButton, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(PlayButton, 50);
```